# Why Webpack Production Build executes code?

Tags: webpack

Iam new to webpack and i try to understand why when running webpack in production mode doesnt include the functions and instead  it show only the output.

I read about tree shaking but this is another thing. Why webpack in production rans the code? Is there any doc about that?

**util.js**

```
export function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}

export function cube(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { cube } from "./util.js";

console.log(cube(3));
```

**bundle.js**

```
(()=>{"use strict";console.log(3*3*3)})();
```

**webpack**

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: ["./src/index"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is being [inlined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) by Webpack's minifier (Terser, most likely).

Since it's obvious that `cube(3)` can only ever mean `3 * 3 * 3`, and there are no other uses of `cube()`, there's no point keeping the function around.

As soon as you add another invocation of `cube()`, it no longer gets inlined.